# Scripted Browser Scapper

Tags: node.js, scraper, node.io

What can I use to achieve the following, script a browser or otherwise make a request to the server, login, browse the site, eg. find links and navigate to those links.

For now, since I am into NodeJS, I was looking at node.io. It allows you to scrape site quite easily but problem is when I try to post (to login) I get nothing back!

```
nodeio = require "node.io"

nodeio.scrape ->

    @post "http://localhost/auth/login", {
        username: "username"
        password: "password"
    }, ->

        console.log "=====After Login====="
```

But I just get

```
OK: Job complete
```

Even if the login fails, I should get to after login `console.log`?

---

Then I was thinking maybe its better to implement this by scripting a browser instead, it will simulate more closely a real request?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium or Watir let you script a browser.  They use the actual browser, so they will be slower than lower level tools, but they do everything a browser will (ie, JavaScript).

Comment: I have tried the Zombie.JS route which doesn't seem to work on some sites (not controlled by me), probably they detect it could be a bot connecting or something, and reject the connection. So am going the Selenium route, works, but its just slower, abit too slow for my liking, but I suppose I can just leave it running. I think the cause for the slowness is that everytime I do a `get(url)`, it waits for the entire page including any ads or scripts to render before continuing?

Comment: I know that Watir waits for the whole page to load (not scripts, though).  I heard that Selenium didn't, but they might have changed that.

Answer (score 2):

node.io seems like it's a good tool for the job, but I'd also recommend [zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/). It seems to be geared mostly towards testing, but the docs look like it'll be great for scraping, too.

If you want to go the scripted browser route, ignore my answer. :)

Comment: It appears some sites block my connection, or somehow it doesn't work as maybe Zombie/NodeIO is meant for testing/accessing sites controlled by you? Maybe I need to set the user agent etc?

Comment: yeah, the sites you're scraping might check your user-agent, or have API rate limits per client/IP.

Comment: Hmm... how can I make Zombie/NodeIO behave more like a real browser? Will just sending correct HTTP headers like user agent work? What are the usual headers sent by a real browser?

Comment: you could always run a little node server on localhost, do a GET with a browser and print out all headers, to directly copy your browser's behaviour :)